# How to Add Language flags in Vaadin 10 Combo box

Tags: vaadin

How to Add Language flags in Vaadin 10 Como box

[image: example]

Comment: Can you add a bit of context? We can't really help you if we don't know what you tried.

Comment: I want to create a language switcher and for that I want to add a language flag before the language text like I showed in Image I attached .

Comment: Check out this example
https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-templates
or this
https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-components

Answer (score 7):

You can use `comboBox.setRenderer()` to build your own layout that will be used.

```
comboBox.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<HorizontalLayout, MyLanguageClass>(language -> {
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    layout.add(new Image(language.getPathToFlag(), language.getName()));
    layout.add(new Label(language.getName()));
    return layout;
}));
```

This example will do a basic HorizontalLayout with an Image and a Label. You can of course adjust this further to your needs.
I used a [ComponentRenderer](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-components) here, but you can also use a [TemplateRenderer](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/using-templates)

Please note that you still have to use `comboBox.setItemLabelGenerator()` in addition to `comboBox.setRenderer()`, because **the renderer is not used for the selected item - only for the item list**. As far as I know, there is no way yet to use a renderer for the selected item.

---

**Edit for Vaadin 13 / Vaadin 14:**
With Vaadin 13+, you can use the Component `Select` to achieve exactly what you want - the selected option also shows a flag!

```
private ComponentRenderer<HorizontalLayout, Locale> languageRenderer = new ComponentRenderer<>(item -> {
    HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    Image languageFlag = new Image("img/languageflags/"+item.getLanguage()+".png", "flag for "+item.getLanguage());
    languageFlag.setHeight("30px");
    hLayout.add(languageFlag);
    hLayout.add(new Span(getTranslation("LanguageSelection."+item.getLanguage())));
    hLayout.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
    return hLayout;
});
private Select<Locale> langSelect;

private Select<Locale> buildLanguageSelection() {
    langSelect = new Select<>();
    langSelect.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
    langSelect.setRenderer(this.languageRenderer);
    langSelect.setItems(new Locale("de"), new Locale("fr"), new Locale("en"));
    langSelect.setValue(UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
    langSelect.addValueChangeListener(change -> UI.getCurrent().getSession().setLocale(change.getValue()));
    return langSelect;
}

@Override
public void localeChange(LocaleChangeEvent event) {
    // because the renderer uses `getTranslation()`, this will re-translate the shown values using the new Locale.
    // if langSelect.refreshItems() ever becomes public, use that instead
    langSelect.setRenderer(languageRenderer);
}
```

**Edit 2:** I published the Class `LanguageSelect` as an add-on in the [vaadin repository](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/language-select) which bases on this code but is much simpler to use. Available for Vaadin 14 only.

```
LanguageSelect langSelect = new LanguageSelect(
    new Locale("de"), 
    new Locale("fr"), 
    new Locale("en")
);
someLayout.add(langSelect);
```

---

[image: result using select]