# How to reload the components in Vaadin after click internationalization Button?

Tags: java, internationalization, vaadin

I use Internationalization I18N in Vaadin. I have a Internationalization class with the method getText.

```
public static String getText(String key) {
        String returnValue = "";
        String value = "";
        String space = " ";
        Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
        try {
            // session specific locale stored in attribute "locale"
            // if you want add a new language then add a new else if with the
            // new Locale like ("fr", "FR").
            if (VaadinServletService.getCurrentRequest() != null) {
                if ((Locale) VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("locale") != null) {
                    if (VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("locale").toString().equals("en_EN")) {
                        locale = new Locale("en", "US");
                    } else if (VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("locale").toString().equals("de_DE")) {
                        locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
                    }
                }
            }
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale);
            value = bundle.getString(key);
            returnValue = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            // Missing key
            try {
                // return the Key
                String keyString = key.replace("_", space);
                returnValue = new String(keyString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnValue + space;
    }
```

I can call this Method from everywhere to use this `getText()` method.
My Components they get a internationalization text by call this method like this:
`label.setCaption(Internationalization.getText("Willkommen"));`

I have now two Buttons "DE" and "EN" for the languages german and english. In the ClickListener of this Buttons i set the new Locale like this:

```
    btnLanguageDE.addClickListener(e -> {
VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("locale", new Locale("de", "DE"));
        });
```

```
btnLanguageEN.addClickListener(e -> {
VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("locale", new Locale("en", "EN"));
logger.debug("Internationalization change to: EN"); 
        });
```

The Problem is, if i click on the Button they set the local but didn't reload the components on the page. It changes only if i reload the page manually.
I tried to call this `UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation();` but no effects.

How can i reload the components with the actual locale ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good [documentation about internationlization / localization](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-i18n-localization.html) with vaadin.

First up, you seem to have implemented your own logic how you can access translated labels with your Internationalization class.
Vaadin has already implemented this; you can let your Internationalization class implement `I18NProvider` (and annotate it with @Component if you're using Spring. If not, you need to register it somehow I think the linked docs explain how) and change your methodname from `getText` to `getTranslation`. Every Vaadin Component (therefore in every view, since view classes must extend a component) can call `getTranslation(keyString);` where the `I18NProvider` is fetched and used.
*All this is optional since you already made similar implementations yourself. But doing it like this would be best practice.*

---

Now to your actual question - You need to let every view that has a translateable string `implements LocaleChangeObserver`. This forces the view to implement the method `localeChange(LocaleChangeEvent event)` which is called *automatically* when the locale of the UI is changed. 
in the `localeChange` method, you can set all the texts anew that are translated.
**There is no need for refreshing the page!**

```
public void localeChange(LocaleChangeEvent event){
    label.setCaption(getTranslation("Willkommen"));
}
```

You can change the Locale of the UI like this:

```
UI.getCurrent().setLocale(myNewLocale);
```

I have shared the code for my Language Selection in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763977/3441504) - I think you will find the example code relevant, as my `Select` component has a valueChangeListener that sets a new Locale - which directly triggers `localeChange`.

Comment: At this topic the documentation is the finest trash.

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed recommend reloading the page, `UI.getCurrent().getPage().reload()`.

Comment: it load the page new but didn't change the text.

Comment: Not refreshing the AppLayout...

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at the I18N Tutorials. You can find them here: [Vaadin Tutorials - I18N](https://vaadin.com/tutorials/i18n)

Cheers Sven

Comment: Page not found!