# Language switching - l10n I18n

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, vaadin

How does language switching work in Java/Vaadin? I have a web application and would like to integrate a combo box, that changes the language of every text in this application. Do i need to mark each text that should get translated manually and define its translation? How complex is it to implement this function into an exting project?

Comment: Some helpful links: [A Guide to ResourceBundle](https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle), [Vaadin docs about I18N](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-i18n-localization.html), [example of a language-switcher in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763977/3441504)

Answer (score 3):

> Do i need to mark each text that should get translated manually and define its translation?

You should use [ResourceBundles](https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle) to store/read translations of strings.

> How does language switching work in Java/Vaadin?

You need to provide a class that implements `I18NProvider`. Documentation about that can be found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-i18n-localization.html)

Once implemented correctly, you will be able to call `getTranslation("HelloWorld")` on any Component (and therefore on any view since they must extend a component), to receive the translation of the key "HelloWorld" defined in the ResourceBundle-file of the current UI-Locale.

Views that extend `LocaleChangeObserver` are notified when the Locale is changed, and then you can call `getTranslation("HelloWorld")` again to find the translation of the freshly set language.

> I would like to integrate a combo box, that changes the language of every text in this application.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763977/3441504) of mine where I posted example code of a `Select` component that acts as a language switcher. It is using both ResourceBundle and I18NProvider. (You can use a ComboBox too, but with the downside that you can only display a String for the selected value)

The important part in that code there is that the Select has a `ValueChangeListener` that sets the Locale of the VaadinSession, which in turn will trigger the `localeChange` method of the LocaleChangeObserver that your view now should implement. In the localeChange method, you can re-translate the translatable Strings of every component in the view; set new texts in `Labels`, set new labels and placeholders for `TextFields`, etc etc.

> How complex is it to implement this function into an exting project?

That depends very much on your definition of `complex`, and how familiar you already are with ResourceBundles. There certainly are less complex topics than this, but I18N is never easy. In my opinion, Vaadin has done a very great job of providing us devs with a way to use I18N in our applications.

Comment: Coming from Android, I must say what Vaadin provides here is trash. 100% trash!

Answer (score 0):

Most people use a sort of translation file system for their localization. Basically you make a text file for each language with a key and value system where you name every translated message with a key and a translated value. You can then use these keys (that should be predefined) to get the correct message for the language you want. These files can be anything really, but if you're looking for a simple java implementation then there are pretty simple ways to do it. For an example look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html).

Comment: So every String, that has to be translated, has to be replaced by a key word. Those key words have to be stored in an extra file together with their wanted translation. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. See the links to blog posts sent by Kaspar. There are code examples.

Comment: @nidaav true, it works similar to how you'd use a hashmap. It just looks for that key and inserts the string value its paired with. When I worked on a website a while ago we would use the english sentence as the key to make it easily readable. This way you can still read the original sentence without needing to look in the localization files. This does, of course, create some overhead since the keys can be fairly long. This is not recommended for long pieces if text for obvious reasons aswell ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this section of the documentation? https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-i18n-localization.html

Comment: This is not really an Answer as expected on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BasilBourque to be fair the question wasn't either